# how to replace single slash with double slash for a variable Using Jmeter In built features

Tags: jmeter

Var1 = ABCD\EF\DE

How can I convert Var1 value from above one to below one using JMeter.

Var1 = ABCD\\EF\\DE

Answer (score 1):

There is a new [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) available since [JMeter 3.1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-31), you can run arbitrary Groovy script in there, for example:

1. Just return the value of `${Var1}` variable with added slashes:

   ```
   ${__groovy(vars.get('Var1').replace('\\\'\, '\\\\\\\'),)}
   ```
2. Update `${Var1}` variable with the new value containing extra slashes:

   ```
   ${__groovy(vars.put('Var1'\,vars.get('Var1').replace('\\\'\, '\\\\\\\')),)}
   ```

Demo:

[image: Groovy update JMeter Variable]

Also be aware of [__strReplace()](http://www.jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#strReplacesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-4-0-font-sup) function available via [JMeter Plugins](http://www.jmeter-plugins.org/) project.

Comment: Wow, this helped me and inspired a lot. (the sequence of seven back-slashes was out my imagination)

However, this is Java, so back-slashes are not needed at all, for file paths can be used the common slash:
 `.replace('\\\'\, '/')`

Answer (score 0):

In Java (/Beanshell) double backslash \ inside a string will represent one backslash .

So for example Run in JSR223 Sampler or BeanShell Sampler

```
Var1 = "ABCD\\EF\\DE";
Var1 = Var1.replace("\\", "\\\\");
```

You will see in response ABCD\EF\DE as you need it.

Comment: I have tried creating Bean Shell post processor and added  

String x = var1;

x = x.replace("\\","\\\\");

var1 = x;

log.info(x);

Error : ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``String x = "BRANCH\UP\SUBS\0453\v1\v1.1a";  x = x.replace("\","\\");  "BRANCH\UP . . . '' Token Parsing Error: Lexical error at line 1, column 20.  Encountered: "U" (85), after : "\"BRANCH\\"

Can you elaborate the solution ?

Comment: I don't think you need x. Use var1 = var1.replace("\\", "\\\\");

Comment: I have used BeanShell sampler to

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions.